# Why is the answer .908 W instead of 9.08?

Tags: power, basic

I tried calculating it on my own and end up questioning why 200k * e^-10 becomes .908 W instead of 9.08 which was what I've calculated 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is Fig. 1.5? Use the preview before hitting 'Post Your Answer'.

Comment: It's just a typo.... Hopefully the author doesn't _really_ think 200000e^-10 is actually 0.908.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why 200k * e^-10 becomes .908 W instead of 9.08

It does not.

Taking as a base and unevaluated assumption that the equations are accurate and applicable, there is a simple math error in the last line of the given solution.

You can verify this yourself with a calculator; the evaluation of the exponential seems correct, but the wrong result is printed for the final multiplication.